# Choosing minimum or maximum values of a specific repeating item from a mixed array

Tags: excel

I have a repeating list of tables for different companies. I need to choose minimum or maximum values of same elements from those tables.

I can not use a macro or pivot like solution because I need to import this excel formula into an excel add-in for calculation purposes.

[image]

As you can see in the example image, I need to choose minimum and maximum interest rates from all the subsidiaries and put it on holding company's table.

I have looked into this problem for  while now but can't event get close to a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did  the answers below work for you? If so please mark as correct. It is something only the person posing the question can do. Click on the green check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that the currencies are in Column B and the holding company starts at line 23:

This would go in C23:

```
=MIN(IF($B$2:$B$21 = $B23,$C$2:$C$21))
```

And this would go in D23:

```
=MAX(IF($B$2:$B$21 = $B23,$D$2:$D$21))
```

These are Array formulas and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when leaving the edit mode. Then copy down.

Comment: My situation was extraordinary and this did not solve the issue. But with the parameters I gave in question, array formulas would solve the issue. So I chose your answer as correct. Thanks :)